# Why initialization and iteration of elements in container adapter are not supported

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize  the elements in stack/queue using initializer_list<> and  iterating  the elements using iterator but both are not supported. I understand they are adapters and implemented using containers but why we can not perform these operations ? 
     The only way to insert elements into these adopter by push() and can print/iterate elements by using top()/pop()/front()/back() methods?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue> 
#include <stack>
#include <initializer_list>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{

 //queue<int> q1{3,4,5,6}; // COMPILATION ERROR
 //stack<int> s1{5,6,7,8};// COMPILATION ERROR

 stack<int> s1;
 s1.push(3);
 s1.push(4);
 s1.push(5);
 s1.push(6);

 //for(auto it: s1) //  COMPILATION ERROR
 //  cout << it <<" ";
 while(!s1.empty())
 {
    cout << s1.top() <<" ";
    s1.pop();
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want to iterate over the "stack" it's really not a stack anymore, and you could use the underlying [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) container directly instead (or a vector or a list, depending on other factors for your use-case)

Comment: Adapted containers should only have a limited interface. Not enough to iterate as you want (I don't expect that after `for(auto it: q1)`, `q1` is empty, whereas it is clear in the manual loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stack<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) and [`queue<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) are two very specialized data structures obeying FILO (first-in last-out) and FIFO (first-in first-out) that wrap around a given container class ([`deque<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) as default). Both [stacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) and [queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) are abstract data types in computer science that support a very slim set of operations, namely adding elements (push/enqueue) and removing elements either at the end (pop) or at the beginning (dequeue). C++'s versions are meant as implementations of these concepts. They are not meant to be used as a general replacement of a container such as `deque<T>` and therefore do not have an initializer_list constructor (elements are meant to be added in an order one after the other), or `begin()` and `end()` members which would be needed for the [iteration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Answer (score 2):

The `std::stack` and `std::queue` container adaptors were presumably designed to be as general as possible. These templates do not "understand" how to store and retrieve their elements.

A stack needs the `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_back()` operations. A queue needs `front()`, `back()`, `push_back()`, and `pop_front()`. So when you push an element onto a queue, it calls `push_back()` on the underlying container, and so on.

In order for stacks and queues to support iteration, they would have to require that the underlying container does as well. Therefore, if you invented a new container that supported `front()`, `back()`, `push_front()`, `push_back()`, `pop_front()`, and `pop_back()`, but not iteration, you could not use that container to construct a stack or queue. The stack and queue adaptors would therefore not be as general as possible.

I hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `stack` and `queue` are not aggregate types and they don't provide initializer-list constructors.